# Converting a calculated Column that uses EARLIER into a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a problem with a column in one of my reports and I need to turn it into a measure so I can use a SelectedValue and change its behavior based on the user input.

The idea of the measure is to take two years, compare building category by building category  between the two years and notice when I have something new (Present in the recent year and not in the old year) that I call acquisition, or when I have something that disappears (Present in the old year but not in the recent year) that I call a disposition

I used to do it with a calculated column and using earlier on the Category, but when I try to convert it to measure, the use of the function EARLIER is different

This is what I have in my calculated column :
(SelectedYear is a variable defined in the same calculated column)

```
Var MyVariable=
CALCULATE('Balance Sheet'[Value],
                All('Fiscal Calendar'),'Fiscal Calendar'[Year]=SelectedYear,
                FILTER(All('Balance Sheet'),
                'Balance Sheet'[Category] = EARLIER('Balance Sheet'[Category]))
```

Then I have another Variable that applies the same logic but on the previous year and I apply an if function to check if it is an acquisition or a disposition.

I tried to change the logic using MAXX to get the comparison between the previous Categories, but I get a "True/False expression is used as a table Filter expression" error

Any idea what I could do to make it work ?

I tried to create a measure using Maxx and multiple other methods like in this blog post https://javierguillen.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/can-earlier-be-used-in-dax-measures/
But all the resources I have found were using earlier to make a cumulated sum and I did not manage to use them

Answer (score 0):

You'd need something like:

```
=
VAR ThisCategory =
    MIN ( 'Balance Sheet'[Category] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Balance Sheet'[Value] ),
        'Fiscal Calendar'[Year] = SelectedYear,
        'Balance Sheet'[Category] = ThisCategory
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not give me the expected result :
The idea is to compare the data from, let's say, 2020, with the one from 2021. See what new biulding "appeared" and "disappeared" the ones that appeared, I show the value, and the ones that disappeared I show the opposite of the value. When I use this method, I do not get the same values, on top of missing some rows, which seem to be the ones not in common between the two years

Comment: Then add a small, sample dataset together with expected results.